# Do we need an [evaluation] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion

We have a new tag, [evaluation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluation):

> For questions regarding the evaluation of experiments, including metrics.

Is this something we should keep?  It seems to me that probably most of statistics could be construed to be about the evaluation of experiments.  I can't help but wonder if this will really help organize the information on the site, or if it is inevitable that it will be used inconsistently over time and lead to more confusion.

If we shouldn't keep it, what should we do?  Should it be deleted, or made a synonym of something (what)?

Comment: As I understand it, "evaluation" for many people is about evaluating the success or failure of a programme/program [non-computing sense], policy, law, or intervention in society, medicine, the environment, etc. That often has a statistical flavour. (Indeed, it is hard to think of good evaluations that don't.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah the description was made in a hurry sorry about that. Here was my thinking: I created a question about aggregating metrics, and the closest tag was `model-evaluation`which is close but not exactly right.

Maybe a metrics tag would have been more appropriate, but that doesn't exist either.

Comment: We do have a [tag:metric] tag. It isn't clear to me that your question needs any of that. Ultimately, you have a [good] question about aggregating over means in a particular circumstance. My 1st thought would be that the tags `[mean]`, `[aggregation]`, & perhaps `[geometric-mean]` would be appropriate & sufficient.

Comment: To me "evaluation" implies a question about calculation of some kind of expression on a computer. I believe that "evaluation" without some adjective is too broad/general and would be misused.

Comment: @gung that's a good point, I've changed the tags.